# Stability analysis for a system of two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

I have this system of differential equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt}=\alpha x-\beta xy\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=\beta xy-\gamma y
\end{equation}

I need to find the critical points and then do a stability analysis. After this I need to find the solutions curves for this system.

I have started like this:
The critical points are $(0,0), (0,\frac{\alpha} {\beta}), (\frac{γ}{β},0)$. Is this correct?

As I understand it I need to create a Jacobian matrix: $g(X)$= $\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & -\beta x  \\
\beta y & -\gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$, where $X=(x,y)^T$

Then form: (also matrices)

$A_1=g(0,0)$= $\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0  \\
 0 & -\gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$,
$A_2=g\bigl(0,\frac{\alpha} {\beta}\bigr)$= $\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0  \\
 \alpha & -\gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$,
$A_3=g\bigl(\frac{γ}{β},0\bigr)$= $\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & -\gamma  \\
 0 & -\gamma 
\end{pmatrix}$

---

My question is how do I know which one is stable? and then how do I form the solution curves.

Comment: The only one critical point is $(0,0)$.  This critical point is stable if and only if $alpha < 0$.  Do you agree?

Comment: I make $A_1,A_2$ and $A_3$ clear with my second edit.

Comment: You need to check the eigenvalues, and eigenvectors (at each equilibrium point), they will give you a local picture near each equilibrium point. Then you might be able to draw global conclusions. Of course everything will depend on the choice of the parameters, so you may have several distinct cases to consider, e.g. all parameters are positive, or all parameters are negative, and so on.

Comment: @Amzoti I just edit the question it is not mine.

Answer (score 1):

The computation of the equilibrium points is not correct. Since you do not give any assumptions on the parameters, let us suppose that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are non zero. you need to solve simultaneously

\begin{equation}
\alpha x-\beta xy=0; \qquad \beta xy-\gamma y=0.
\end{equation}

The point $(0,0)$ is clearly an equilibrium point. Observe that $x=0$ implies $\gamma y=0$ and that $y=0$ implies $\alpha x=0$. Thus, your last two equilibrium points are not correct.

Now, suppose $(x,y)$ is not the origin. Then $(x,y)=(\gamma/\beta,\alpha/\beta)$ is the other equilibrium point.

The Jacobian is the matrix

\begin{equation}
J=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha-\beta y & -\beta x\\
\beta y & \beta x-\gamma
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

then

\begin{equation}
J|_{(0,0)}=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha& 0\\
0 & -\gamma
\end{bmatrix}; \qquad J|_{(\gamma/\beta,\alpha/\beta)}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\gamma\\
\alpha & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

You could construct the following table, depending on the eigenvalues of $J$ at each point. Let $p_1=(0,0)$, $p_2=(\gamma/\beta,\alpha/\beta)$

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\alpha & \beta & \gamma & p_1 & p_2 \\ \hline
 + & + & + & saddle & center \\ \hline
 + & + & - & source & saddle \\ \hline
 + & - & + & saddle & center \\ \hline
 + & - & - & source & saddle \\ \hline
 - & + & + & sink & saddle \\ \hline
 - & + & - & saddle & center \\ \hline
 - & - & + & sink & saddle \\ \hline
 - & - & - & saddle & center \\ \hline
\end{array}

And then, for example, have the following phase portraits (at least for the first 2 cases, you could try to do the rest)

[image: First item of the table]

[image: Second item of the table]